# Pass id trough <a> tag to bootstrap modal PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of items on the webpage and to the right I have Edit buttons.

```
echo '<a href="#myModal?id='.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="modal" >';
```

How do I properly pass parameter trough `<a>` tag to the bootstrap modal? My code above doesn't work with `?id='.row['id']'` part. I'm getting the **Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #myModal?id=12**. But `<a href="#myModal data-toggle="modal">Edit</a>` opens bootstrap modal.

Thank you

Comment: why do you need to pass `?id='.$row['id']`  ?

Comment: to populate the bootstrap modal with data from mysql db.

Comment: Please clarify "doesn't work." Are you getting a php error/warning/notice when generating the page? Are you getting any console errors when trying to click the link? Are you having trouble reading the `id` param in whatever code this goes to?

Comment: You should use ajax and jquery to get data from mysql to bootstrap modal.

Comment: why I can't use php instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the value through this..

`href="#myModal?id='.$row['id'].'"`

because this is the modals name..

Comment: How can I pass it then?

Comment: You can use jquery to pass the id and get your data from your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only by ajax request. You must populate the modal using ajax function.

Take the click event of a tag

Eg:

```
  <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="aTagclass" data-id="1">open modal</a>

$('.aTagclass').click(function(){

// you can take data-id by

Var id= $(this).data('id');

// call your ajax function using the id
//populate modal

// open modal here

});
```

**Note: above code may have errors.**